# Any templates to handle Projects, track and log issue, upload docs all on single page

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, issue-tracking, project-templates

I am new to share point. The business requirement is to have a share point site with a dedicated page to each project we handle. My manager wants the design to be in such a way that they can upload any docs, create and track issue, log risk, move status of the project, and have a calendar dedicated only for the project to mark the milestones - all on the same page. Can anyone tell me if I should be using a list, document library or any template exists for this? Would I need Share point designer to achieve the above mentioned? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need SharePoint Designer to accomplish this. Instead you add all of these tasks, issues, documents, status and calendar on a web part page, or a wiki page - whichever you prefer. But first things first:

In all site content (gear icon, site content) you add

- an Activity list
- a Custom list (which you can call Issues)
- a Calendar

You already have a document library on the web which you can use for the documents of the project.

Now, you browse to the start page of the site, and edit the page (gear icon, edit page). When you edit the page you get to see the Ribbon, where you add your web parts of the lists you just created. Add them, and move them into order which you need, and you'll have just the things your assigned to have.

A couple of things to notice: Every web part (of your lists) have different views. You can hide or show columns any way you want, configuring each web part to make a good readable page.

It can be overwhelming at first, but if you start with one web part, you'll soon find out what you can do with it. And if you need specific help, search this site since it's unlikely someone before you haven't had the same issue your facing. If you can't find answer, ask another question.

Be brave and good luck!